# CSS3 inset not working

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to replicate the following look and feel for a Navbar using HTML5 and CSS3 but with no success.

How can I replicate the look the attached image using HTML5 and CSS3?

[image]

My HTML is:

```
                            <div id="budget-nav-container"> 
                            <div class="budget-navbar">
                              <ul>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Jan</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Feb</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Apr</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">May</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jun</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jul</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Aug</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sep</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Oct</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Nov</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dec</a></li>                                    
                              </ul>
                            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                        </div>
```

and CSS is

```
#budget-nav-container{
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: centre;
}

.budget-navbar {
    text-align: centre;
    padding: 1px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000 inset;
}

.budget-navbar ul {
  width: 650px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

.budget-navbar li {
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.budget-navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.budget-navbar a:hover{
  height: 100%;
  text-color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.budget-navbar .active a{
  height: 100%;
  text-color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

I have tried using the inset option and box shadows but my limited understanding of CSS3 is making things a bit difficult.
I would really appreciate some help here!

Cheers,

Amzy

Comment: question title edited and details entered. Please un-hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what did NOT work for you, but I edited your code to add in an inset `box-shadow`.  Here's the syntax of the CSS property `box-shadow` for future reference:

`box-shadow:` `none` *or* `h-shadow v-shadow blur-value spread-value color`.

I put the code into a JSFIDDLE:

### http://jsfiddle.net/6f30u3dg/1/

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks mate! your nudge pushed me in the right direction. I realised that i needed to add the box shadow to the li element itself. All good now!